# check_box_tag using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any help please?

I have a column in database called citizen, I want to use check_box_tag using ajax which on check will submit the citizen check box value.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use jQuery.
2. Catch the click event on that checkbox
3. Fire off an Ajax command (probably a PUT) to UserController#update (I'm assuming you're modifying a User) with the value of the checkbox (1 if set, 0 if unset)
4. ...
5. Profit (?)

Caveat for step 3 is that you already have a User object saved. If this is a new User, then you don't need ajax.